# copy mongodb file from windows to ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am tring to copy `mongodb` files from my Windows system to an Ubuntu instance (Amazon AWS).

I put the `msdDB.0` AND `msdDB.ns` from windows on `/var/lib/mongodb` (I see that the path on `/etc/mongodb.conf`) and run `mongod` (`sudo service mongod start`). After that, I run my node `server.js`.

All looks fine, but when I enter to my web I can't enter with my register user (that I put when I start the web on windows).

Comment: Better way to me seems to be backup and restore http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/ although i haven't tried this myself.

Comment: No way for simply copy past?

Comment: You can check what is different by using "mongo" in command line on windows and on ubuntu, select your db and user collection and find user then check the difference